# calling javascript From userControl

Tags: c#, jquery, .net

I have a userControl "foo.ascx" registered on and loaded on index.aspx. On foo's page_load I am calling a javascript method which is created on foo's markup page. I am using `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` **The problem I am running up against is, during the loading of the user control the ClientScriptBlock code seems to be calling the javascript before the javascript is rendered**. Below is an example of the page source i have and **the problem IS StartCounter("25:10"); IS being called before the function is created**. Any help would be great. Thank you very much.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Assets/Javascript/jQuery.js" ></script>
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head><title>
    </title></head>
    <body>
       <form name="form1" method="post" action="default.aspx" id="form1">
    <div>
    <input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKLTUxOTYxMTY4OGRkounMyYFBle29baVV35X4KzMIHn4=" />
    </div>   
 <type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
StartCounter("25:10");//]]>
   </script>
       <div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Assets/Javascript/Timer.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
      });
    function StartCounter(startTime)
    {
      $('#counter').countdown({
        stepTime: 60,
        format: 'mm:ss',
        startTime: startTime,
        digitImages: 6,
        digitWidth: 53,
        digitHeight: 77,
        timerEnd: function() { alert('end!!'); },
        image: "/Assets/Images/digits.png"
      });
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to register the js in this way in RegisterClientScriptBlock from server side it will solve the problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ StartCounter("25:10"); });
```

Comment: will do, they have a built in timer and need to wait another minute